# How can I start my MainActivity after Facebook Login to Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate Facebook login to my app through Firebase. When the user clicks on "Continue with Facebook" button, I see a blue progress bar and then the text on the button changes to "logout". I intent to open another Activity when the Login succeeds. I have used startActivity() method for that. However, nothing happens. Please help!

Below is the extract of onCreate() method of my Login Activity

```
     callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    // Register your callback
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            // If the login attempt is successful, then call onSuccess and pass the LoginResult
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    // The HomeScreen.class should load, it is not happening.
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,HomeScreen.class));
                    // I get this Log on my screen, which is proof that this loop is executed
                    Log.w("TAG", "User ID: " +
                            loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "\n" +
                            "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                }
                // If the user cancels the login, then call onCancel
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Canceled login through Facebook",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // If an error occurs, then call onError
                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            " Facebook Login failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.w("FB failed", exception);
                }
            });
```

I am allowing for Google login also through Firebase, for this I have written the onActivityResult method. It is this -

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

        } else {
            // Handle failed signin here
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Google Sign In Failed, Please try with Facebook or Email!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are using fragment than add this to you fb login button

```
buttonLogin.setFragment(this);
```

and in your onSuccess() method, try this

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity() ,HomeScreen.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this,HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use permissions when you are trying to login with facebook. For example:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_photos"));
```